# Improper Integral Involving Logarithmic Function

Tags: logarithms, improper-integrals

The integral I was facing trouble with is the following:
  $$\int^1_0 \frac{\log x}{1+x}\,dx$$
I substituted,  $$x=\tan^2\theta$$
This is what I got:
$$2\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 \frac{\log(\tan \theta)}{\sec^2\theta} \cdot 2\tan\theta\sec^2\theta  \, d\theta\\
=4\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0 \tan\theta\cdot\log(\tan\theta)\,d\theta$$
I can't proceed any further. What do I do next? Is this the right approach?

Comment: After integration by parts, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046219/find-int1-0-frac-ln1xxdx)

Answer (score 13):

Expanding the series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, your integral is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \int_0^1 x^k\log x \, dx.$$ Using integration by parts, with $U=\log x$ and $dV=x^k\,dx$, we have that $$\int_0^1 x^k \log x \, dx=-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2},$$ and so $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{1+x}=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}$$ $$=-\eta(2)=-\frac{\pi^2}{12},$$
where $\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet Eta Function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) Evaluating $\eta(2)$ is exactly as difficult as evaluating $\zeta(2)$ (it's not hard to show that $\eta(2)=\zeta(2)/2$) so there will be no "easy" integration by parts solution to this integral. See this answer for more details on how to evaluate $\zeta(2)$: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2).

Comment: Ingenious! Never thought a solution like this

Comment: @Raffaele It is the general approach to handle logarithms multiplied by rational functions.  Turn the thing into a series and refer to known values, which have their own derivations and proofs.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Another general approach to these types of problems is with complex analysis and the residue theorem.

Comment: @EricNaslund :P That's for all integrals tho.

Comment: @EricNaslund I am not supposed to know the Eta function yet.

Comment: @EricNaslund All I am allowed to use are gamma,beta functions and all other elementary approaches.

Comment: @Tanisha: As I showed in my answer, evaluating your integral is equivalent to evaluating $\zeta(2)$. Any method of proof must therefore also provide a a proof that $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$, and this is not easy to do.