# How to calculate $ \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^2 e^{-t}}{(1 + e^{-t})^2} dt $?

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate

$$ \int \limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^2 e^{-t}}{(1 + e^{-t})^2} dt  $$

I used variable replacement $u = e^{-t} $ and got the integral

$$ \int \limits_{0}^{1} \frac{ \ln^2u}{(1 + u)^2} du  $$

Wolfram says that it is $\frac{\pi}{6}$. But I have not idea. How can I get this result?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Title and first integral in post are different!

Comment: I would assume the substitution was $u=e^{-t}$.

Comment: @Fakemistake, sorry for this! fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 u}{(u+1)^2}du
&= \int_0^1{\ln^2 u}\>d(\frac{u}{u+1})\\
&=- 2\int_0^1\frac{\ln u}{u+1}du = -2 (-\frac{\pi^2}{12})=\frac{\pi^2}6
\end{align}

where [$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln u}{u+1}dt =-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046219/finding-int1-0-frac-ln1xxdx/3826136#3826136)