# How would I integrate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+ \sqrt{1-x^2})}{x}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+ \sqrt{1-x^2})}{x}\,dx$$
I have known this equals to $\frac{\pi^2}{16}$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Power series look a way

Comment: Hint: call it $I$. With $x=\sin t$,$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin t+\cos t)\cot tdt=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin t+\cos t)\tan tdt,$$where th second $=$ imposes $t\mapsto\pi/2-t$. Averaging,$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(\sin t+\cos t)dt}{\sin2t}=\frac12\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+\sin2t)dt}{\sin2t}=\frac12\int_0^1dc\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{dt}{1+c\sin2t}.$$

Comment: @J.G: That was a very cunning reduction! Just the complete the whole thing, With $u=\tan(t/2)$ \begin{aligned}
\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{dt}{1+c\sin 2t} &= \frac12\int^{\pi/2}_0\frac{dt}{1+c\sin t}=\frac12\int^\infty_0\frac{du}{(u+c)^2 + 1-c^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\big(\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\big)\Big)
\end{aligned} So
$$ I=\frac{1}{4}\int^1_0\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\big(\tfrac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\big)\Big)\tfrac{dc}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}\stackrel{\alpha=\sin c}{=}\frac14\int^{\pi/2}_0\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha\Big)d\alpha=\frac{\pi^2}{16}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note

\begin{align}
I=&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(x+ \sqrt{1-x^2})}{x}\,dx\\
= &\int_0^1 \frac{\frac12\ln(1-x^2)+\ln(1+ \frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}})}{x}\,dx=\frac12I_1+I_2\tag1
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}\,dx\overset{x^2\to x}=\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx+ \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx
= -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx\\
I_2 &= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)}x
\overset{x=\frac t{\sqrt{1+t^2}}}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t(1+t^2)}dt+ \int_1^\infty \underset{t\to1/t}{\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t(1+t^2)}dt}\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}t dt - \frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+t}dt
=\frac54 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}t dt 
\end{align}
Substitute $I_1$ and $I_2$ into (1) to obtain

$$I= \frac34 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}t dt =\frac34\cdot \frac{\pi^2}{12}=\frac{\pi^2}{16}
$$
[$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}t dt=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046219/finding-int1-0-frac-ln1xxdx)